# Why there isn't any sub-stream capability of mersenne twister random number generator in MATLAB and how we can solve it?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, neural-network, random, mersenne-twister

I'm using parallel computing and i need different sub-streams (independent sub-stream) of random numbers in every worker (logical core) in `MATLAB`. When i set `sub-streams` to `mlfg6331_64` or `mrg32k3a` My performance with neural network in `parfor` loop is so low but when i generate random weights outside of `parfor` by `rnf - mersenne twister` my performance is higher.

- Why `MATLAB` doesn't support `mersenne twister` as sub streams? My `MATLAB` version is `R2014a`. Is any support of this feature in `R2014b`?
- How can i create independent streams of random numbers using `mersenne twister` before `parfor` and insert (for instance weights of neural network) to `parfor` loops? (for example using a loop before `parfor loop`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that MATLAB doesn't support substreams with Mersenne twister, it's that Mersenne twister doesn't support substreams.

If the choice of RNG is affecting the performance of your NN, something bigger is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for answer Sam. It is affecting out-sample performance! With `Mersenne twister` i have `85%` classifications accuracy but without it the classification accuracy is near `70%`! You said something bigger is going wrong! what is that?